# Claryfying about Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I might sound silly by asking the question about Knockoutjs which is given in this link: 
http://jsfiddle.net/VR5aa/
The code is given as below:

**HTML**

```
<!-- This is a *view* - HTML markup that defines the appearance of your UI -->

<p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>
<p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>

<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
<p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>

<p>Full name: <strong data-bind="text: fullName"></strong></p>
```

and JS:

```
// This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI
function AppViewModel() {
    this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
    this.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");

    this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();    
    }, this);
}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Whats confusing me in Knockout is the usage of Brackets. eg in text binding we can use **text:firstName()** and yet this works too. 
 I also tried following:

```
console.log(typeof this.firstName);   //returns function
console.log(typeof this.firstName());  //returns string
```

So Please can someone elaborate the usage of () in Knockout JS. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are binding to an observable, which firstName is, then you may **either** do

```
text:firstName()
```

OR

```
text:firstName
```

and knockout will be smart enough to do the right thing.  Now, if firstName were a function, like

```
firstName: function(){
    return "Bert";
}
```

then you would have to manually call the function in the bidning with parentheses

```
text:firstName()
```

If you were to just do

```
text:firstName
```

with a plain JavaScript function, then a string representation of the function would show up in your UI, which would be the text of the function itself in modern browsers.

Here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/14642/) of this in action.

Answer (score 0):

you can check this playlist as it contains simple videos about knockout

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLCyiZP-cRGcAozahbiVrFQ2FvIUDLG9XU

it starts from basic